# Why aren't these header files #include guarded?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, xv6, include-guards

I am doing some projects on the xv6 operating system. In [one of the header files](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/proc.h) `struct proc` is defined.

```
// Per-process state
struct proc {
  /****I added this****/
  struct spinlock lock;
  /**********************/
  uint sz;                     // Size of process memory (bytes)
  pde_t* pgdir;                // Page table
  char *kstack;                // Bottom of kernel stack for this process
  enum procstate state;        // Process state
  int pid;                     // Process ID
  struct proc *parent;         // Parent process
  struct trapframe *tf;        // Trap frame for current syscall
  struct context *context;     // swtch() here to run process
  void *chan;                  // If non-zero, sleeping on chan
  int killed;                  // If non-zero, have been killed
  struct file *ofile[NOFILE];  // Open files
  struct inode *cwd;           // Current directory
  char name[16];               // Process name (debugging)
};
```

I added an element of type `struct spinlock` (defined in [spinlock.h](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/spinlock.h)) to `struct proc`.

```
// Mutual exclusion lock.
struct spinlock {
  uint locked;       // Is the lock held?

  // For debugging:
  char *name;        // Name of lock.
  struct cpu *cpu;   // The cpu holding the lock.
};
```

That caused some compilation problems . First, I got this error.

**In file included from exec.c:8: proc.h:46:19: error: field ‘lock’ has incomplete type**

Which should be easy to fix: I just added `#include "spinlock.h"` to proc.h. This time it threw this error.

**In file included from proc.h:1, from console.c:15: spinlock.h:2:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct spinlock’**

It made me notice something strange about this code and why I was having this redefinition errors: neither spinlock.h nor all of the other header files are `#include` guarded.

So, instead of adding `#include "spinlock.h"` to proc.h, I had to go to exec.c and do `#include "spinlock.h"` before `#include "proc.h"`. After that, more errors came. exec.c was not the only file that included proc.h but not spinlock.h before. I ended up doing `#include "spinlock.h"` before `#include "proc.h"` in more than 10 files.

I don't understand why they didn't #include guard any header file when this is considered so basic to prevent errors. With that, I would have added `#include "spinlock.h"` to proc.h and compile successfully instead of going to every file that included proc.h and including spinlock.h before.

I'm assuming this was not an error because the code was written by professionals and there must be a good reason for that.

Comment: https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/pull/207 Add header guards

Comment: @TedLyngmo `ELF_H_5FA195AE_CAAF_11EE_8AD1_90B11C0C0FF8` is certainly future proof but wouldn't something shorter be better? `XV6_ELF_H_` (e.g.)?

Comment: @CraigEstey: why does it matter?  The long name with a GUID/UUID embedded in it will be used twice (in `#ifdef` and `#define` — and maybe a comment after `#endif`), but that's all.  No-one else needs to know what the value is.  You'll not be testing that macro name in other files, will you?  You shouldn't be, at any rate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Linux `.h` files do. Let's just say that I've been reading and writing C code for 40+ years and this is the first time I've ever seen anything like this in real code.

Comment: @CraigEstey Since these didn't have any guards at all, I'm sure noone will check them. I also made reasonably sure to make them unique because some of the names looked like candidates for conflicting `define`s. I also happened to have made a script exactly for adding missing guards :-)

Comment: @CraigEstey: In my experience (also over 40 years), I've not seen hashes or UUIDs used in header guard names, but they are a good idea in that they ensure that the same header guard won't appear in different header files, even if the base name of the header is the same (so `dir1/header.h` and `dir2/header.h` won't interfere with each other).  Most of the code I've worked on uses some variation on `HEADER_H_INCLUDED` for `header.h` (and there's rarely completely systematic naming).

Comment: Also, whenever I've seen `#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED` / `#include "header.h"` / `#endif` in source files including a header, I've seen problems because the header guards are now a public property — part of the interface for the file. If the header guard changes (and that's something that should be a matter local to the header file alone), the code in the other files includes obsolete lines which only complicate that code. The header is still included (subverting the attempted optimization), but the old header guard name is left lurking in the source where it has no business being.

Comment: Additionally, modern compilers are good at optimizing `#include` lines.  They note if the header has been included previously and don't reopen and reinclude it if it is protected by a header guard.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I too have an automatic script for adding header guards. But, mine (by default) uses the rightmost two levels of the name (e.g.) `dir1/header.h` --> `DIR1_HEADER_H_` To me, the UUID is just too long/crufty (if you must, how about the GMT creation time of the `#ifdef` (in us/ns) expressed as split hex (e.g.) `HEADER_H_01020304_05060708_`). But, also, this is xv6 (the source code from unix v6). Its compiler only supported 8 char names (truncated to 8). So, here, I'd keep that spirit if I were doing a "restoration"

Comment: @CraigEstey The uuid I use is both time _and_ node based so I prefer that over a purely time based one. It's also standardized so one can decode them afterwards if needed.  `uuid -d 5FA195AE-CAAF-11EE-8AD1-90B11C0C0FF8` for the example you picked.